# error a la hora de agregar la dependencia spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot

tengo un problema a la hora de agregar la dependencia Spring security, al momento de arrancar el servidor sale este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto no tiene que ver con Spring Security, si no que está relacionado con la persistencia. Has agregado la dependencia Spring Data JPA que utiliza Hibernate por detrás, pero Spring Boot no puede arrancar debido a que falta el '*driver*' para conectarse a una base de datos. Mismo problema que pasa cuando utilizas JDBC pero no agregas el driver.

El LOG te sugiere posibles acciones: 'H2', 'HSQL' o 'Derby', estas son bases de datos que pueden ser utilizadas en memoria (en RAM) sin persistir los datos en el disco. Si tienes por ejemplo XAMPP, Wamp u otro, puedes agregar [mysql-connector-j](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) como dependencia.

```
<dependency> <!-- Spring Data JPA with Hibernate -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency> <!-- MySQL Connector Driver (Agregar) -->
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Si prefieres utilizar una base de datos en memoria sin tener que instalar o configurar una, puedes ver una de las dependencias sugeridas, normalmente en guías o vídeos se utiliza [H2](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Esta ultima dependencia actualmente posee 2 vulnerabilidades de gravedad media. Puedes buscarla en https://start.spring.io/ pero aun contendrá las vulnerabilidades. No se si afecta directamente o solo en entornos de producción donde puedes ser atacado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser que H2 en el futuro halla solucionado las vulnerabilidades, debe revisar ya que te brida ciertas ventajas cuando estas ejecutando en una maquina diferente, o compartiendo la aplicación por ejemplo en GitHub, GitLab, etc...

Comment: vale gracias, si era eso al momento de agregar la dependencia borre el conector de mysql